# "so much..." or "such..." discrepancy

Tags: phrase-requests, adverbs, such

I have the sentence:

"They begin to recognize why so much discrepancy and confusion persists within this subject "

My question is: should it be "so much" or "such"? 
Would I need to do something like "such discrepancy and so much confusion..."?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't a dictionary solve this problem for you?  "Such" means "this type of" and "so much" means "this [large] amount of."  That should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both can be correct depending on the meaning.**

- "So much discrepancy" means "this amount" of discrepancy (by implication being a large amount). They begin to recognize why this amount of discrepancy exists.
- "Such discrepancy" means "this kind of discrepancy". You could use this when there has been a small (or large) amount of discrepancy and they are realizing why discrepancy like this exists.

Comment: "Such discrepancy" can also informally be taken to mean "so much discrepancy". An English professor might frown on it, but people use it in that way all the time. "It's such hassle", "Such whining!", etc.